# How do I clear white spots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I could be wrong, but I don't think they're fireflies. I made trees and used a particle system to place them along another object. The leaves on the trees are double-sided planes. In a test render, the trees looked fine on their own. But when I ran a preview render using the particle system, some leaves look completely white now. I'm using the Cycles Render engine, by the way.

[image]

Comment: I like this render, even with burnt highlights on the trees.  Are the leaves glossy, and reflecting light directly into the camera?

Comment: Oops... Surely enough, that was the problem. I tried using just a regular diffuse shader, and it looks just fine now. Silly mistake.

Comment: @Sunayama instead of writing [Solved] on the title, please write your own answer explaining how you solved your issue. Not only it might help others that have a similar issue, but that will take this post of the "unanswered" list.

Comment: please read http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer